# Connection ssh refused

Tags: ssh

I am trying to connect to my ssh session on my web shared hosting and i get this error

```
   ssh user@my-ip -v
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/user/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 107.180.44.157 [107.180.44.157] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I want to precise that before one year the last time i connected ot was working.

Comment: Please validate my answer if it does helped you

Comment: No the port 22 open

Comment: Sorry i have not seen the (connection closed by remote host)  on the verbose output i have edited the answer hoping it will help

Answer (score 2):

There is two possible reasons since you have not made any change to sshd configuration to prohibit the access for certain users@hosts , you can try the below from a direct console access:

1-  Try to remove  the entry for the remote machine in ~/.ssh/known_hosts on your local system to reset fingerprints / keys and connect back again.

2- There is a firewall behind the remote machine.

3- There is a high load on the server that is preventing the resource to be served. Try to increase the above parameter in /etc/ssh/sshd_config :

```
**MaxStartups**
```

4- Check /etc/hosts.allow and /etc/hosts.deny

5- Check whether **sshd** have the lost the access to some libraries files. It can be due to updates on some ssh dependant libraries. To check this  :

```
sudo lsof -n | grep ssh | grep DEL
```

Try to reach the server from the console and check both the service status and the firewall rules.

To check weither the ssh port is opened  :

```
nc -zvw3 <remote-server> 22
```

***If nothing of the above helped so reboot the server***